# Single view on multiple pages

Tags: entities, views

1) I created a content type **Portfolio-Item**. In this type a text field **Project-Url** was defined.

2) I created a **view** containing a gallery using jQFX module displaying content of **Portofolio-Item** elements which where published.

I wan't to add this **view** to different pages containing different projects portfolios.

a) *Is it possible to add a "**filter criteria**" or "**contextual filter**" that would compere the **Project-Url** field with page URL and filter available **Portfolio-Item**'s to display only proper one's.* ?

b) Is there any easy way to achieve this?

c) Can **contextual filter**'s be used with **regular expressions**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the sandbox project [Views arguments in filters](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/itangalo/1086472) (download it via Git)

With this module you can move a contextual filter down into the normal filters so that everything that you can do with normal filters can then be applied to the contextual filter.

> **How to use this module**
>
> To make use of this module, configure your view as usual, but use the
>   following steps when adding arguments.
>
> - Use the argument "Global: Null" to denote the input arguments your    view will make use of. This argument not alter your query in any way, 
>     but you can still use validators and actions if no argument is
>     present as usual. And title, breadcrumbs, et cetera. Sweet.
> - Add a filter, and instead of adding a filter value manually, you    enter %1, %2, et cetera to filter on the first or second input
>     argument. That's it!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use a [Viewfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield) or the [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) Module. With both of them you can attach a view to an entity and add arguments. I personally prefer EVA to do stuff like this. Very handy and allows you to use the same in different contexts without exposing it to the site admin directly.